# Maven : Parent project not resolved, transitive dependencies not used for compiling

Tags: maven-2, build, parent, dependencies

After searching and trying a lot of things I need a Maven maven :)
So, my problem is that on my development box (which is Windows 2003) I can build my maven project, but on the Bamboo server (x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux) it fails because one of the modules doesn't have a library and the compiling doesn't find a class.
The class is found in a transitive dependency, dependency that it seems to me that is not resolved.
I've run the command "mvn -X clean install" on both boxes and compared the output.
The only change I think it's relevant is

On dev-box

```
[DEBUG] Retrieving parent-POM: pl.com.abg.iacsro:sapscndp-claimprocessing:pom:1.0-SNAPSHOT for project: pl.com.abg.iacsro:sapscndp-claimprocessing-api:jar:DEV2010 from the repository.
```

On Bamboo box

```
[DEBUG] Retrieving parent-POM: pl.com.abg.iacsro:sapscndp-claimprocessing:pom:1.0-SNAPSHOT for project: null:sapscndp-claimprocessing-api:jar:DEV2010 from the repository.
```

It seems to me that maven doesn't resolve the parent of the module, because later in the build process I've seen (on Bamboo box)

```
[WARNING] POM for 'pl.com.abg.iacsro:sapscndp-claimprocessing-api:pom:DEV2010:provided' is invalid.
Its dependencies (if any) will NOT be available to the current build.
[DEBUG] Reason: Failed to validate POM for project pl.com.abg.iacsro:sapscndp-claimprocessing-api at Artifact [pl.com.abg.iacsro:sapscndp-claimprocessing-api:pom:DEV2010:provided] 
Validation Errors:
[DEBUG] 'dependencies.dependency.version' is missing for pl.com.abg.iacsro:systemcore-jobs-api:jar
[DEBUG] 'dependencies.dependency.version' is missing for pl.com.abg.iacsro:workflow-crossconflictresolution-api:jar
[DEBUG] 'dependencies.dependency.version' is missing for pl.com.abg.iacsro:iacs-commons-objectfactory:jar
[DEBUG] 'dependencies.dependency.version' is missing for ro.siveco.iacsro:farmerregistry-api:jar
```

I've also found this

```
[WARNING] POM for 'pl.com.abg.iacsro:sapscndp-claimprocessing-api:pom:DEV2010:provided' is invalid.
```

but I've checked and validated myself the pom of the dependency against the xsd, so the pom is valid.

Do you have any idea how to resolve this ?

Many thanks!

P.S. : In case maybe I've overlooked something, here's the full listing from the Bamboo box http://dl.dropbox.com/u/402296/install.txt

Answer (score 1):

When I see such an entry:

```
[DEBUG] Connecting to repository: 'Artifactory-internal-repository' with url: 'http://192.168.0.59:8081/artifactory/repo'.
Downloading: http://192.168.0.59:8081/artifactory/repo/pl/com/abg/iacsro/onthespotcheck/1.0-SNAPSHOT/onthespotcheck-1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
[DEBUG] Using Wagon implementation lightweight from default mapping for protocol http
[DEBUG]   Artifact resolved
[WARNING] POM for 'pl.com.abg.iacsro:onthespotcheck-checks-api:pom:DEV2009_2:provided' is invalid.
```

I'm tempted to ask if there is anything particular to say about `onthespotcheck-1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom`?

As a side note, you have a bunch of:

```
for project: null:artifactId:version
```

that I find pretty weird. Why is the groupId `null`? Anything worth to mention about your pom?

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, sometimes I don't see the whole picture.
This is a legacy project I try to straighten up, so it's full of little mistakes.
I've erased the .m2 folder, and I've reproduced the behavior on my dev box.
I'm going to take all the dependencies and see if they have correct poms.